# JSP page is not downloading manifest.json

Tags: html, tomcat, manifest, progressive-web-apps

I have included a manifest.json file in my .jsp page for PWA as below. But its not making a call to download the file itself. I have hosted the solution on tomcat server.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="assets/js/font-awesome.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <base href="">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="BI/manifest.json?v=1.01" />

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

However, there is no request in Network tab for downloading the file.
I have checked the MIME type of tomcat server which already has extension type json and type application/json.

Is there anything i have to do? Or any other MIME type?

Comment: Did you find a solution?